# Unable to 'Enable-Migrations' due to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell version 10 missing

Tags: c#, shell, visual-studio-2012

Currently trying to enable migrations for my database using an MVC application and I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Now, there is solutions for this on SO, but it is relating to the Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package, which when I go to the Microsoft web page [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30670) to download it gives me a 404 error on the web page.

Is there any other way I can get around this issue? I've tried a few things with the global.asax file and the configuration file for Visual Studio itself, but have had no luck. I'm just trying to learn MVC and this is hindering that greatly.

Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: Website works fine here?

Comment: So you can click continue and proceed to the download?

Comment: Well, it redirect me to my MSDN login page from wich I'm currently locked out. Hm. Maybe some issues on their end, since you are getting a 404?

Comment: Not very helpful on their part. Is there anywhere I could download the package without going to MSDN?

Comment: I had the same problem, and after being unable to find an answer anywhere, I discovered that the download works if you pick a different language than English. So what I did was, I changed the language to Italian, clicked the download link, then on the URL I got redirected to, I changed the "it-IT" slug in the URL to "en-CA", went to that page, and downloaded the resulting file. Long story short, here's the link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-CA/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30670